# Multiple buttons do the same

Tags: reactjs

I am building an app in React, that is connected to an API I have written before. Buttons are renderizing but all of them change at the same time. I need advice about how can I write my code in order to separate the functionality.

My app renderize with a .map the same number of Buttons as appointments which is an array. All of them change when this.state.shown change but I need to separate all the buttons in order to only show the one that I clicked. Right now, when I clicked in one of them, this.state.shown change its value so all the buttons change because all depends of the same variable. I am looking for advices about how I can separate this.

```
class AppointmentsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            appointments: [],
            isLoading: false,
            shown: false, //Variable to know if a button need to change and render the component
            customerUp: false
        }

        this.toggleCustomer = this.toggleCustomer.bind(this);
        //this.showCustomer = this.showCustomer.bind(this);
    }

    toggleCustomer() {
            this.setState({
                shown: !this.state.shown
            })
    } //This function change the value of shown when a Button is clicked.

    render() {
            const {appointments, isLoading} = this.state;

            if(isLoading) {
                return <p>Loading...</p>;
            }

            return(
            <div>
                <h2>Lista de citas</h2>
                {appointments.map((app) =>
                    <div key={app.id}>
                    <p>Fecha: {app.appointment}</p>
                    <p>Cliente: {app.customer.name}</p>
                    <p>Id: {app.customer.id}</p>
                { this.state.shown ? <Button key={app.customer.id} color="danger" onClick={() => this.toggleCustomer() }>Ocultar cliente</Button> : <Button key={app.customer.id} color="danger" onClick={() => this.toggleCustomer() }>Ver cliente</Button> } 
                { this.state.shown ? <CustomerView id={app.customer.id} /> : null }
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

How can I reorganize my code in order to render the Buttons separately?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1: You can make shown state a object like:

```
state = {
  shown:{}
}

toggleCustomer(id) {
 const updatedShownState = {...this.state.shown};
 updatedShownState[id] = updatedShownState[id] ? false : true;
            this.setState({
                shown: updatedShownState,
            })
    } //This function change the value of shown when a Button is clicked.

    render() {
            const {appointments, isLoading} = this.state;

            if(isLoading) {
                return <p>Loading...</p>;
            }

            return(
            <div>
                <h2>Lista de citas</h2>
                {appointments.map((app) =>
                    <div key={app.id}>
                    <p>Fecha: {app.appointment}</p>
                    <p>Cliente: {app.customer.name}</p>
                    <p>Id: {app.customer.id}</p>
                { this.state.shown[app.customer.id] ? <Button key={app.customer.id} color="danger" onClick={() => this.toggleCustomer(app.customer.id) }>Ocultar cliente</Button> : <Button key={app.customer.id} color="danger" onClick={() => this.toggleCustomer() }>Ver cliente</Button> } 
                { this.state.shown[app.customer.id] ? <CustomerView id={app.customer.id} /> : null }
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Method 2: Make a separate component for Button and Customer

```
return(
                <div>
                    <h2>Lista de citas</h2>
                    {appointments.map((app) =>
                       <Appointment key = {app.id} app = {app} />
                    )}
                </div>
            )
        }

class Appointment extends Component {
state = {
shown: false,
}

 toggleCustomer() {
     this.setState({
         shown: !this.state.shown
    })
}
render() {
const { app } = this.props;
return (
   <div key={app.id}>
     <p>Fecha: {app.appointment}</p>
     <p>Cliente: {app.customer.name}</p>
     <p>Id: {app.customer.id}</p>
     { this.state.shown ? <Button key={app.customer.id} color="danger" onClick={() => this.toggleCustomer() }>Ocultar cliente</Button> : <Button key={app.customer.id} color="danger" onClick={() => this.toggleCustomer() }>Ver cliente</Button> } 
    { this.state.shown ? <CustomerView id={app.customer.id} /> : null }
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Let me know if it works and the method you prefer.

Comment: This! The second method works in my specific scenario. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate component for your button (`buttonComponent`) inside your **AppointmentsList** component and pass the shown has props and the in `componentDidMount` of  `buttonComponent` copy the props to the **state** of **buttonComponent**.

This way each button will have its own **state**, which manages `shown`.

**Button component:**

```
import react from 'react';

interface buttonComponentProps{
  shown: boolean;
}

interface buttonComponentState{
  shown: boolean;
}


class buttonComponent extends react.Component<buttonComponentProps,{}>{
 constructor(props:buttonComponentProps){
   super();
   this.state{
     shown:props.shown
   }
 }

 ....
}

export default buttonComponent;
```