# use same function for different buttons

Tags: reactjs

I have created a button at the bottom of the page which when clicked open a modal.
Now I have a button in a header. I want that when we click on that header button it should too open the modal. That is how can we use the same function which is used for the button which is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Just but copying the button from one place to another...

Comment: you should have a handler that bother buttons can talk to. usually this is done in a state management system like redux

Comment: provide some code which you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple buttons do the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944838/multiple-buttons-do-the-same)

Answer (score 0):

**Button clicks should set state. State decides if modal is shown**

One way of doing it with hooks is having the buttons set state with a boolean value that decides if the modal is shown.

```
const Component = () => {

  const [modalOpen,setModalOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setModalOpen(true)} >
        Open Modal 1
      </button>
      <div>
        Your other content
      </div>
      <button onClick={setModalOpen(true)} >
        Open Modal 2
      </button>
      <Modal show={modalOpen} />
    </div>
  )
}
```